# How to disable tls for specific traefik ingress in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, traefik-ingress

I am using traefik ingress controller in Kubernetes. It is configured to redirect all request to https and terminate tls connection before passing the request to backend service.

Is it possible to only enable http for one particular ingress config but https for other ingresses ? Any example would be helpful.

I only want to enable http(no https) for this ingress

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: testdomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: test-service
            port:
              number: 8080
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create the one ingress with the config like

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
annotation:
  kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "traefik"
  ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "false"  
  ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
  traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/frontend-entry-points: http
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: testdomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: test-service
            port:
              number: 8080
```

you can get more idea about the annotation from here : https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/v1.6/configuration/backends/kubernetes/

Comment: This didn't worked. http request is getting redirected to https.

Comment: above ingress i have used with 1.7, which version you are running ? if you are using middleware make sure you have set proper config in it.